# How use ClearText textarea When i am click radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

1.Step(Unicode RadioButton is Checked) 
 TextetArea **notClear** when **Unidcode Radio** is Checked But **Zawgyi Radio** is checked Textarea is **Clear**.

2.Step(Zawgyi RadioButton is Checked)
TextetArea **notClear** when **Zawgyi Radio** is Checked But **Unicode Radio** is checked Textarea is **Clear**.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="kb" value="uni" id="unikb"/>Unicode</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="kb" value="zawgyi" id="zawgyikb"/>Zawgyi</label>
<textarea id="desp" class="form-control rows="5"></textarea>
```

How use Jquery

```
   $("input").click(function(){

      if ( $(this).val()=='uni' || $(this).val()=='zawgyi'){ 
    $("textarea#desp").val();
   }
    else{
    $("textarea#desp").val('');
   }
 }) ;
```

i wanted this style

[image]
textarea is not clear.

[image] 
textarea is clear

**AND**
[image]
textarea is not clear. 
[image]
textarea is clear

## [SEEDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/hLuk2bhx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the else clausure wrong, jsfiddle fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/hLuk2bhx/9/
Now it's working... (:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(e) {
    if ( $(this).val()=='uni'){ 
        $("textarea").val('');
    }else{
        $("textarea").val('');
    }    
});
```

---

After your comment i've updated your code making it more dynamic, i've create a var to control the last statement.

```
var lastChecked = undefined;
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(e) {
    if ( $(this).val() != lastChecked && (typeof lastChecked !== 'undefined')){ 
        $("textarea#desp").val('');
    }
    lastChecked = $(this).val();
});
```

Hope that it helps your problem.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLuk2bhx/23/

Comment: yes thank friends, i wanted clear textarea when change radio button. but you answer is always textarea clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code , plz see this JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hLuk2bhx/22/

Code changed

```
 $("textarea#desp").val();  ->   $("#desp").val(''); //You have to assign an "" empty string as its value to clear the textarea content

 esle -> else
```

Added html as below

```
<input type="hidden" id="previouschecked" name="previouschecked" value="" / >
```

And I have added an input[hidden] to storethe previous value, So it should looks like

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(e) {
if ( $(this).val() !=$("#previouschecked").val()){ 
    $("#desp").val('');
}
    $("#previouschecked").val($(this).val());
});
```

Since you have an ID on your textarea so you can use $("#desp") directly

"esle" is a typo so your code is broken that won't run correctly

Comment: Your answer good, but it is not ok because i wanted clear textare when radio button is change checked..

Comment: The radio buttons does clear the textarea when the radio button is changed.

Comment: Okay I got your point, updated the code here  http://jsfiddle.net/hLuk2bhx/22/  I have added a input hidden to store the previous selected radio button, please try